# How can i avoid overall page load during Search filter

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, search, autoloader

Supposed to search by filter in my site loads all pages, i need to load only my contents not all my pages.

screen shots :

[image]

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html see this extension.

Comment: @Shrikant : after installed you suggestion, i get error like

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Tqb60Lt.png

Comment: It might get conflicted with some of your custom code, check if you are overriding some of the product blocks or model which they are trying to override from their config.xml. The extension works perfectly on my store .

Comment: Not working......

Comment: you need to check the config.xml xml of extension and it's rewrites, and see if your custom code or any other extension code rewrites the same class. Or you can try other extensions, there are many layered navigation ajax extension out there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50438/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-shrikant).

Comment: I mentioned few things on chat.